# whitespace or tab in the output perl

Tags: perl

I have this code that works perfectly for me in listing objects that belong to a specific value bin. The only problem is that I'm not able to get an output with whitespace or tab delimiters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.14.0;
my $file = "test_counter.txt";
open DATA, '<', $file or die "$!";
my %hash;
while (<DATA>){
    next if /^\s*$/m; )
    my ($key1,$key2,$val) = /^(\w.+)\|(\w.+) (1|(\d+)(\.(\d+)))$/;
    $val = int($val*10)/10;
    $hash{$val}{$key1}++;
    $hash{$val}{$key2}++;
    }
for (-10..10){
    $_ = $_/10;
    say "$_\t", $hash{$_} ? keys $hash{$_} : '';
    }
```

The input test_counter.txt file looks like this:

```
data|all 0.12
cup|bed 0.16596
bed|all 0.221
cup|all 0.21123
data|bed 0.388
cup|bed 0.35
bed|data 0.412
data|all 0.5236
data|cup 0.565
bed|all 0.6174
all|cup 0.65
cup|data 0.678
```

And the output I get is:

```
 -1 
-0.9    
-0.8    
-0.7    
-0.6    
-0.5    
-0.4    
-0.3    
-0.2    
-0.1    
0   
0.1 bedcupdataall
0.2 bedcupall
0.3 bedcupdata
0.4 beddata
0.5 cupdataall
0.6 bedcupdataall
0.7 
0.8 
0.9 
1
```

I would like to have the same, but with a tab or whitespace between the objects, or ideally a tab delimited output with an empty place when the object is not found in the bin. Something like this:

```
 -1 
    -0.9    
    -0.8    
    -0.7    
    -0.6    
    -0.5    
    -0.4    
    -0.3    
    -0.2    
    -0.1    
    0   
    0.1 bed cup data all
    0.2 bed cup  all
    0.3 bed cup data
    0.4 bed data
    0.5  cup data all
    0.6 bed cup data all
    0.7 
    0.8 
    0.9 
    1
```

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to join all the elements of an array together with some delimiter:

```
join "\t", keys %{$hash{$_}};
```

e.g:

```
say "$_\t", $hash{$_} ? join "\t", keys %{$hash{$_}} : '';
```